# App / script for cleaning up SVG files?

Tags: svg, code-cleanup

I'm looking for an app or a script (web service) that can clean up SVG files, by that I mean removing possible copious data such as metadata. When creating the SVG file I've used standard settings in Adobe Illustrator. Upon export the paths look like this -

```
M 678.567,252.999 c-0.546-1.307-3.898-3.118-5.005-4.007c-1.596-1.276-1.42-3.375-3.09-4.381c-4.297-2.571-9.604-3.125-13.746-5.916
```

While I need them be cleaned up and reordered in way like this -

```
M 600.375,693.40625 598.75,695.03125 596.125,694.34375 594.57422,700.50391 592.25,700.16406 591.875,702.59375 593.875,705.53125 592.75,706.40625 593.9375,710.53125  592.75,710.65625 590.3125,712.90625 589,711.96875 587.1875,712.90625 586.8125,711.40625 584.125,710.53125 581.9375,711.03125
```

Fairly new to working with SVG. What I need these paths for is drawing up a map with Raphael JS and it seems only to take the paths in that particular way.

I tried Scour (http://www.codedread.com/scour/) but with no success unfortunately (the web service isn't working and there were problems running the procedure with Terminal).

Comment: Please explain what you mean with path cleanup and reordering, do you only want straight line segments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it looks like Raphaël should support [all of the path syntax](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path) in SVG 1.1.

Anyway, [ReadySetRaphael.com](http://readysetraphael.com/) is a site that provides conversion of a subset of SVG to Raphaël code.

Comment: Just the kind of site I was looking for! Thanks Erik. They even have an example of an interactive map there which seems to be working fine with the other path syntaxes as you mentioned.

Comment: Please be aware that the example they provide (http://jsfiddle.net/FJrNN/2065/) works with Raphael 1.5.2 (see the JSFiddle option in the left) but not with version 2.1.2 (at least with Chromium 31.0). I've found this tool useful but still can't make it work with some of my SVG files.

Answer (score 0):

Convert .ttf (or other format) to .svg: [https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-svg](http://icomoon.io/app/#/select) .

Convert the svg. to icons separated [icomoon.io/app/#/select](http://icomoon.io/app/#/select),

-Import icons'
-Select the icons that you want export 
-Click en 'Generate SVG, PNG, PDF'